# Android Parcelable with JsonObject

Tags: android, serialization, parcelable

In order to initialize my new Fragment, I need to send an object as parcelable one. 
These are the fields it contains:

```
private String sessionId;
private String status;
private JSONObject typeAttributes;
private JSONObject kindAttributes;
```

The problem is that JSONObject is not parcelable. If I just use writeValue method in writeToParcel method, I get unacceptable class error. 
Moreover, JSONObject is not even Serializable.

Also, typeAttributes and kindAttributes are dynamic, so each time my app starts they have different fields with different values.

If anyone knows how to solve it, please help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would use `JSONObject`'s [toString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#toString()) method to return a `String` which you can easily save to a parcel.

Then to create the object from the parceled `String`, just use the `JSONObject` [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject(java.lang.String)) that takes a `String` and it'll auto-populate those object's fields for you.

Comment: thanks a lot, I didn't know that JsonObject can easily be cast to String and vice versa

Comment: Keep in mind that doing this a lot can incur performance degradation. Parcelable exists because serialization was too slow for regular UI/OS level data passing

Answer (score 1):

I would go with this approach.

1- Create a Pojo class which implements serializable

2- Build the object of that class

3- Send the Object as serialazable one

```js
public class POJO implements Serializable{
    private String sessionId;
    private String status;
   // private JSONObject typeAttributes;
    // SUPPOSE THIS JSONObject CONTAINS TWO FIELDS AS NAME AND AGE SO I USE TWO MORE FILDS
    String name;
    String age;

    //....... WRITE GETTERS AND SETTERS

}
```

Let me know if you need further explanation for building this POJO object Inside activity and then send it to as a serializable